# Slow Speed of UI Operation and Data Loading (DataGridView) C# Program

Tags: c#, performance, user-interface, datatable, datagridview

My application have Parent form and child form. By clicking on a **Button** the child form loads into parent form. On Clicking the **Button** two tasks are executed.

**1)** The Panel in the Parent form Changes its color. And the Label Text is changing.

**2)** The child forms opened within parent form and fill the **DataGridView** on form_Load. The Buttons in child form also changing its Color.

My Access database has now only 20-30 records. DataTable loaded with these records and assigned to **DataGridView**. But above tasks execution speed is slow. It takes 3-5 Second to run all these. **How should the speed is improved?**

The Code for **Parent Form** below where **Button** is placed is below.

```
public partial class frmDashboard : Form
{
    private Button currentButton;
    private Random random;
    private int tempIndex;
    private Form activeForm;
    public frmDashboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        random = new Random();
        btnCloseChildFrm.Visible = false;
        this.Text = string.Empty;
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea;
    }

    // for Dragging Form
    [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
    private extern static void ReleaseCapture();
    // for Dragging Form
    [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    private extern static void SendMessage(System.IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private Color SelectThemeColor()
    {
        int index = random.Next(ThemeColor.ColorList.Count);
        while(tempIndex == index)
        {
            index = random.Next(ThemeColor.ColorList.Count);
        }
        tempIndex = index;
        string color = ThemeColor.ColorList[index];
        return ColorTranslator.FromHtml(color);
    }
    private void ActiveButton(object btnSender)
    {
        if(btnSender != null)
        {
            if(currentButton != (Button)btnSender)
            {
                DisableButton();
                Color color = SelectThemeColor();
                currentButton = (Button)btnSender;
                currentButton.BackColor = color;
                currentButton.ForeColor = Color.White;
                currentButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                pnlTitleBar.BackColor = color;
                pnlLogo.BackColor = ThemeColor.ChangeColorBrightness(color, -0.3);
                ThemeColor.PrimaryColor = color;
                ThemeColor.SecondaryColor = ThemeColor.ChangeColorBrightness(color, -0.3);
                btnCloseChildFrm.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
    private void DisableButton()
    {
        foreach(Control previousBtn in pnlMenu.Controls)
        {
            if(previousBtn.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                previousBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(108, 156, 196);
                previousBtn.ForeColor = Color.White;
                previousBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, object btnSender)
    {
        if(activeForm!= null)
        {
            activeForm.Close();
        }
        ActiveButton(btnSender);
        activeForm = childForm;
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.pnlDesktopPane.Controls.Add(childForm);
        this.pnlDesktopPane.Tag = childForm;
        childForm.BringToFront();
        childForm.Show();
        lblTitle.Text = childForm.Text;
    }

    private void btnStudents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenChildForm(new frmStudents(), sender);
    }

    private void btnClass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveButton(sender);
    }

    private void btnCloseChildFrm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (activeForm != null)
            activeForm.Close();
        Reset();
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        DisableButton();
        lblTitle.Text = "HOME";
        pnlTitleBar.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(108, 156, 196);
        pnlLogo.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
        currentButton = null;
        btnCloseChildFrm.Visible = false;
    }

    private void pnlTitleBar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0);
    }
}
```

The code for **Child Form** where DataGridView is Loading is under.

```
public partial class frmStudents : Form
{
    // Database related Declaration
    private OleDbCommand command;
    private DataTable dTable;
    public frmStudents()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    private void frmStudents_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadTheme();

        // Show Students
        StudentsFillGridView();
    }
    private void LoadTheme()
    {
        foreach (Control btns in this.Controls)
        {
            if (btns.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                Button btn = (Button)btns;
                btn.BackColor = ThemeColor.PrimaryColor;
                btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
                btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = ThemeColor.SecondaryColor;
            }
        }
    }

    private void StudentsFillGridView()
    {
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT s.RollNo, s.SName, s.FName, s.DOB, c.Class, s.[Section],s.Picture from students as s left outer join classes as c " +
                "on c.ClassID = s.ClassID", conn);
            dTable = new DataTable();
            dTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
            // Sorting data in DataTable 
            dTable.DefaultView.Sort = "RollNo";
            dTable = dTable.DefaultView.ToTable();

            dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SrNo", typeof(Int32))); // Adding "Serial No" Column to DataTable

            int srNo = 1;
            foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
            {
                row["SrNo"] = srNo;// for row in DataRow in Datatable
                srNo++;
            }
            dTable.Columns["SrNo"].SetOrdinal(0);
           
            dgvDisplay.DataSource = dTable; 

            // Change Column Headings
            dgvDisplay.Columns["SrNo"].HeaderText = "Sr No";
            dgvDisplay.Columns["RollNo"].HeaderText = "Roll No";
            dgvDisplay.Columns["SName"].HeaderText = "Student Name";
            dgvDisplay.Columns["FName"].HeaderText = "Father Name";
            dgvDisplay.Columns["DOB"].HeaderText = "Date Of Birth";
            dgvDisplay.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove these lines: `dTable.DefaultView.Sort = "RollNo";`  and `dTable = dTable.DefaultView.ToTable();`. The latter is not needed in any case, the former can be removed since you can add `ORDER BY` to the query.  Change `Control btns in this.Controls` in `Button btns in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()`, so you loop only Button Controls and you can remove `if (btns.GetType() == typeof(Button))` and the following cast. `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill` is expensive, but not so expensive. If this procedure takes 3-5 seconds, it looks like the database is in a network share.

Comment: Since you already know the Fields Names, you could add the DGV's Columns in the Designer, including the Column that you're adding to the DataTable (not sure what's the use of this). Try to remove any AutoSize feature to compare the time needed. ++ REMOVE THIS `private OleDbCommand command;`, plus OleDbCommand is a disposable object, declare it with a `using` statement as the Connection.

Comment: the database isn't network share. its Local. I have removed these lines that u suggested to remove, Changed 'Controls' to Controls.OfType<Button>(). It improves but still taking time to change the label color and text of label.

Comment: It still taking time to change the color of (**pnlTitleBar** and **pnlLogo**) and text of **lblTitle**. Also I want to fill columns size to the datagridview size. if i changed it to none `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None`. How should I fill the width of datagridview? @Jimi

Comment: Your question is related to *Slow Speed of Data Loading*. The data is loaded in `frmStudents`. What happens in the other Form I cannot say, that code is partial. You may have cascading events generated by those changes. What you MUST remove is that OleDbCommand Field (I hope you're not using it anywhere else, you cannot reuse OleDb objects like that). I suggested to remove any AutoSize features in your DGV to test the difference with an without. Break your code in pieces: remove the Theme-like part and see if what's slowing down your app is actually the data loading or the UI operations.

Comment: Have removed the OleDbCommand Field declared it with `using`. When I remove the **DGV** code the Color changing of Panels and text changing works fine and UI operations works normally.